# Solve for $X: X^{49} = 60$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

An unknown value is raised to a known power which results in another value, also known. How do you find the unknown value?

Comment: In ancient times (e.g. the 1970s) you could use logarithms (twice) and antilogarithms

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could apply the $\ln(\cdot)$ function to both sides to get:

$$\ln(x^{49})=\ln(60)$$

$$49 \ln(x) = \ln(60)$$

$$\ln(x) = \frac{\ln(60)}{49}$$

using the exponent function $e^{\cdot}$, noticing that $e^{\ln(x)} = x$:

$$x= e^{(\frac{\ln(60)}{49})}=e^{0.08355805229}=1.08714832491$$

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I kind of suspected log could be used, but it's been so long since I used a log function I had forgotten how they worked. Thanks.

Comment: This seems amazingly roundabout when the radical operation, by definition, immediately answers the question.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins, you are correct. The radicals approach was already posted as a separate (and more popular) answer when I wrote the above.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins: On the other hand, logarithms are often the easiest way to _compute_ high radicals.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: If that was a concern, then it should be explicit in the question and/or answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can apply the $49$th root on both sides to get

$$ X = 60^\frac{1}{49} = \sqrt[49]{60}$$

Comment: If we are considering real numbers then $$ X = \pm 60^\frac{1}{49} = \pm \sqrt[49]{60}$$
On the other hand, if we are considering complex numbers then there 49 roots for this equation.

Comment: If we are considering real numbers 49 is odd so there aren't any negative 49th roots of 60.  We only need to consider negative roots of positive numbers if we are taking even roots.  On the other hand only odd power roots exist for roots of negative numbers.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say, but this doesn't make sense to me: *"We only need to consider negative roots of positive numbers if we are taking even roots."*

Comment: @flawr $(-1)^3\neq 1$. In fact, $x^3=1$ has no negative solutions

Comment: But how about $x^3= -1$? The only real root is $x = -1$ which clearly is negative. Here we still need to consider *"negative"* roots even tough it is *not* and *even* power.

Comment: $60>0$. An odd root of a real number is negative iff the number is negative.

Comment: Exactly, that is true.